# How to translate a sentence with 'shall'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice

I am hoping to translate the following from English to Latin:

"From Your Grace, I shall know no fear."

Latin structure however doesn't use 'shall' apparently.

What would the most accurate translation into Latin look like?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I suggest registering your account, so that you can edit your post and get notifications about answers. There are ways to express similar things in Latin. Would you be satisfied with a future tense ("I will know"), or are you looking for some other nuance? Elaborating on the message you want to convey really helps find the best translation.

Comment: Until I read Draconis's answer, I hadn't considered that you were using 'your grace' much as one might address a royal personage as 'Your grace.' I read it as more like 'the grace that you confer.' Perhaps you can clarify your intended meaning? I was taking the whole 'From Your Grace' phase to mean something like 'As a result of the grace that you confer'.

Comment: The Archpoet addressed his patron with meticulous politeness as 'Praesul.' https://homepages.wmich.edu/~johnsorh/MedievalLatin/Texts/Arch.html This patron was both Archbishop-elect of Cologne and an Archduke. "Ā tē, praesul, ..."

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is, Latin has a lot of *morphology* on the verbs: lots of ways that you can change the verb word to express a distinction. English doesn't, really: English verbs are marked as "past" (*walked*), "non-past" (*walk*), "non-past with a single subject who's not the speaker or the listener" (*walks*), and nothing else. So in English we have to use extra words to make other distinctions, such as "will" + "non-past" = "future" (*will walk*).

In this particular case, "shall" is being used to give a future meaning. In Latin, you would change the verb word itself, instead of adding another word to it.

So I would translate your phrase somewhat literally as:

> *Ā tē, domine, nullum metum sciam.*
>   From you, lord, no fear shall I know.

"Your grace" is somewhat difficult to translate since it's an idiom the Romans didn't use; literally it would be *grātia tua*, but that doesn't feel right to me. So I swapped it out for "lord", a generic respectful title, but you could also use e.g. *rex*, "king", or something else more specific.